# Angular service visibility is really important?

Tags: angular

I was trying to finish the angular.io/tutorial but then I focused on a particular advise, [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#display-the-message-from-heroservice). Angular says, and I'm quoting, it can

> only binds to public component properties

Is this really true?
Trying to learn something more than just the tutorial itself, I tested myself if the HTML could access the service in the exported class either if it was private, protected or public and it did! Everything worked.

So my questions are three: the statement I quoted from the Angular tutorial documentation is true? It is just a way of programming, a "good habit"?
What is happening in the Angular lifecycle that makes someone thinks that the visibility of the service should not be private?

Following OOP guidelines, it's a normal behavior to show resources of an object to a private property of his own, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular runs in different modes for either development or production. When you compile your project for production with AOT (where templates are compiled into JavaScript). The Angular compiler will throw a *private* or *protected* access error.

The run-time compiler which is the default mode for development only compiles the templates in the browser. After the TypeScript has been converted to JavaScript and access modifiers have been lost.

So you've only tested what happens during development mode.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask so, how can I compile throught AOT? Because I thpught I already did that via “tsc” but that probably was a mistake, reading your answer. Or not?

Comment: It's an option on the CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files

Comment: Ng build —prod —aot